# Linq Query Failed with Concat Operator

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, wcf

I trying to developing banking system . I trying to join three tables records into single table . but the problem is when i compile it i got following errors.

**Error CS1929  'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Concat<>(IQueryable<>, IEnumerable<>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<>**

Here is the Linq Query .

```
  public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
        {

            var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var q1 = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(w => new
                {
                    w.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)null,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount,
                    w.Date
                }).ToList();

                var q2 = context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new
                {
                    d.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                    d.Date
                }).OrderBy(r => r.Date).ToList();

                var q3 = context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new
                {
                    //You should perform same anonymous type which you want to concat
                    Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                    e.Account_Fees
                }).ToList();

                var inOut = q1.Concat(q2).Concat(q3).ToList();**//Error on this line**



                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                return js.Serialize(inOut); // return JSON string
            }
        }
```

Here is the Database Record [image]

Here is the Model Class.
[image]

Comment: Lol `concat` - you noob. You need a `join`

Comment: you mean instead of concat  i should use join

Comment: Actually no, what you are doing is crazy. Can you at least not use dynamic types for one. Create a proper class you want all these records to go into.
Then on your `select new <thenewclass>`
That will avoid some problems. Then what you want is the `AddRange` function to concat lists.

Comment: i  got lots of suggestion i am making the changes but still i failed to solve it

Comment: You are trying to add `Account_Fees` from `Current_Account_Details`. If you decided to go this route, you need to add `Account_Fees = (decimal?)null` to the other two `Select`s, and also add a fake `Date = DateTime.Now` to the last `Select`. This would ensure that all three lists use the same anonymous type.

Comment: That's not the only problem right, but yea, feel free to update my answer below @dasblinkenlight

Comment: You can use Worthy7's suggestion, too. It's odd that you are trying to mix all three in a single list, though, because the records are very different.

Comment: Worthy7's suggestion is required to create new class and he did not say what should be properties of this class@– dasblinkenlight

Comment: @Mohammad it is very basic, that's why. Sorry but you are really asking a noob question here. By using dynamic classes you are just trying to take shortcuts and not doing things properly. Dynamic means no strong type checking and that's why you are running into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
        {

            var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
            List<AccountTransaction> accountTransactions = new List<AccountTransaction>();
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {
                accountTransactions.AddRange(context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(w => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    AccountNumber = w.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = 0,
                    Withdrawal = w.Amount,
                    Date = w.Date,
                    Fee = 0
                }).ToList());

                accountTransactions.AddRange(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    AccountNumber = d.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = d.Amount,
                    Withdrawal = 0,
                    Date = d.Date,
                    Fee = 0
                }).OrderBy(r => r.Date).ToList());

                accountTransactions.AddRange(context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    //You should perform same anonymous type which you want to concat
                    AccountNumber = e.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = e.Account_Balance,
                    Withdrawal = 0,
                    Date = null,
                    Fee = e.Account_Fees
                }).ToList());

                var inOut = accountTransactions;



                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                return js.Serialize(inOut); // return JSON string
            }
        }

public class AccountTransaction
{
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Deposit { get; set; }
    public decimal Withdrawal { get; set; }
    public string Date{ get; set; }
    public decimal Fee { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I Updated it will everything you should need.

Comment: Mate you have not told me what your properties are. You are trying to merge 3 different classes : Current_Account_Deposit, Current_Account_Withdraw, Current_Account_Details. I didn't know that they don't really have dates in them, adjust the class accordingly

Comment: Why are the dates in the database in various formats? That's just bad. Is this a school exercise?

Comment: Work it out yourself, your original question is about fixing a concat issue. Using a proper class will fix that problem, don't drag me into fixing all your issues, I'm going to downvote and report your question if you do

Comment: I made Date a string, was that so hard?